# crear una nueva columna en un dataframe usando otra columna

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con una columna que indica el precio pero esta guardado como un string y el simbolo $, quiero quitarselo y despues convertirlo a un double . Estoy probando a hacer una nueva columna que se sea igual a la que ya tengo con el string sin el $.

```
df.precio = df.price[1:]
```

Pero no hace nada, es decir se sigue copiando el símbolo $ en la columna precio. Me han sugerido que haga varios replaces en respuestas anteriores pero salía este error

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,063.00'**

Me he metido en el fichero y creo que lo que falla es que ese valor que estaría en la fila 348 está entrecomillado pero el resto de "prices" no.

He vuelto a añadir más replaces para cambiar las comillas por espacios

```
df.price = df['price'].str.replace('$','').replace(',','').replace('"""',"").astype(float)
```

Pero me vuelve a salir el error

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,063.00'**

Comment: NO resumas los errores. Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y vas añadiendo código modificado junto con mensajes de error que obtienes. "Me sale lo mismo" es una mala idea porque le ocultas info portencialmente relevante a la persona que sabe más e intenta ayudarte ;)

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con este código:

```python
df['precio'] = df['price'].str.replace('$','')
                          .replace(',','')
                          .replace('"','')
                          .replace(' ',np.nan)
                          .astype(float)
```

Debería salir como resultado:

```
| price | precio |
|-------|--------|
| $1,063|  1063  |
```

Comment: me da este error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,063.00'

Comment: Es porque hay una coma y se reconoce como string. También debe ser excluido. Prueba el codigo que actualice

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Entiendo. entonces puede ser que haya espacios, deberias agregar otro replace: .replace(' ','') y si hay cuadros en blanco: .replace(' ',np.nan)

Comment: nada sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: Entiendo, revisa tu data. Para que sea float solo puede estar el punto. No pueden estar otros símbolos o espacios. Si encuentras algo usa replace

Comment: vale acabo de encontrar el error y es que en el fichero ese precio sale "$1,063.00" mientras que el resto $87.00 no tiene esas comillas

Comment: pero no consigo hacerlo añadiendo mas replaces

Comment: Que raro. He actualizado el cod. Lo he probado y elimina los símbolos( $ ,coma,  " , espacios). De no funcionar el problema sería otro

Comment: Hola Alexander. Edité tu respuesta con la intención que veas cómo dar mejor formato al código. Al leer la respuesta, no supe por qué tiene tantos _replace_ que, según la pregunta, no hacen falta, y ahora veo que hay una cantidad de información adicional en comentarios. Es un problema que ocurre al responder preguntas que están incompletas o mal formuladas. Queda esperar que @AlexRodriguez o tú editen la pregunta y hagan ver los requerimientos adicionales (tan sencillo como poner ejemplos de los datos de entrada). Te invito a leer [answer] y bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te dejo el primer voto!